# Checkstyle Regexp to catch all console printing in Java

Tags: java, regex, checkstyle, system.out

I have this Checkstyle block to stop people from printing to console in my project:

```
<module name="Regexp">
    <property name="format" value="((System\.|(out|err)\.print)|printStackTrace)"/>
    <property name="ignoreComments" value="true"/>
    <property name="illegalPattern" value="true"/>
    <property name="message" value="No printing to console, use a logger."/>
</module>
```

Where the regex is `((System\.|(out|err)\.print)|printStackTrace)`

However, someone snuck this in: `out.println` 
by importing `import static java.lang.System.out;`.

So I updated the regex to: `((System\.(out|err))|printStackTrace|(out|err)\.(print|write|append))`

**My question is:** does this regex cover all ways to print to console in Java? Does anyone have a better regex that they use in Checkstyle?

Comment: `\b(?:System\.)?(?:out|err)\.(?:print|write|append)` should work. Or, `\b(?:System\.)?(?:(?:out|err)\.)?(?:print|write|append)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The author's solution catches also this case: `PrintStream debug = System.out; debug.print("text");`

Comment: Why not just forbid System out and err all together regardless of what method they call?

Comment: because there are other ways to print, e.g. ```Throwable#printStackTrace()```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want people to use `System.out.println`, then the best thing you can do is to argue their job is in danger and menace them with *other countermeasures*. (Please, I'm joking, never do this) :)

They can just do something like

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class App 
{
    public interface wvs {
        void abc(Object o);
    }

    static final wvs bwz = out::println;  /* this is the only reference to 
                                           * println, but you can hide it 
                                           * in another part of the 
                                           * application */

    static void blah(wvs o, Object oo)
    {
        o.abc( oo );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" ); /* this will be filtered */
        blah(bwz, "another message by courtesy of LC"); /* will this? */
    }
}
```

and get you crazy looking for calls to `System.out.println()`.  You can even write a `Logger` class to print to the console bypassing the `Logger` configuration. :)

As a hint, *Never try to prove the human intelligence by force, you'll lose*.  As a good manager, try to convince your people to act as expected.  Convince them of the benefits of using Loggers, but never try them by brute force.

try to offer free beer to them if you see no console output from your application in one month... That works almost always.